# Meaning of "overall magnitude" of a number

Tags: java, numbers

I'm stumped by the meaning of "overall magnitude" in the Java language specification:

> Widening primitive conversions do not lose information about the overall magnitude of a numeric value.

Is it "order of magnitude", or "absolute value"?  Or something else?

Comment: The way I see it, it basically means "the abstract conceptual value" as opposed to the actual sequence of bits that is used to represent the value. By the way, `float->double` conversion does **not** preserve overall magnitude.

Comment: @biziclop - not if it's `strictfp` - then it shouldn't lose any information at all: "*from float to double in a `strictfp` expression (§15.4), does not lose any information at all; the numeric value is preserved exactly.*"

Comment: @AndyBrown Yes. It's just the way this is expressed in the JLS is a bit weird: first they state that it doesn't happen, then five paragraphs later they add a caveat that erm...actually, without `strictfp` it does happen.

Comment: @biziclop could you give an example to illustrate what you mean by "abstract conceptual value"?

Comment: @Julian Re-reading it, I probably phrased it wrong. If you take the `float` number `200.4` for example, a widening conversion will always preserve the higher order digits. It may lose precision (the lower order digits), so you may end up with a `long` value of `200`, but it's still in the same ballpark. Whereas if you convert `200.4` into a `byte` (a narrowing conversion), you end up with a completely different number: `-56`.

Comment: @biziclop So you're saying it's possible to lose precision but not magnitude?  Based on what I've read, I'm inclined to believe that.  But I find it counter-intuitive.

Comment: Or in a more formal notation: if `f(x)` is the conversion function, `|x-f(x)| <= |x|` for every `x` in a widening conversion, while the same is not true for every `x` in a narrowing conversion.

Comment: @biziclop So magnitude is only said to be lost by conversion if `|x-f(x)| > |x|`?  If so, then magnitude is more of a range or boundaries sort of concept than a specific value.

Comment: The whole idea of a widening conversion is that the range of values covered by the target type is wider than the source type. But they may not have an exact representation of the source value (for example in a `float->long` conversion, in which case a suitably close value is picked. In a narrowing conversion there is a possibility that the source value is completely outside the range of the target type.

Comment: @biziclop I get widening. What I'm interested in nailing down is magnitude. And I still don't have a clear definition.

Answer (score 4):

From the Wikipedia article, [Magnitude (mathematics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnitude_(mathematics)):

> In mathematics, magnitude is the size of a mathematical object, a property by which the object can be compared as larger or smaller than other objects of the same kind.

In plain English, the magnitude of 32767 is 32767.  The magnitude is equivalent to the value of the number.

In the JLS specification, I think they are using magnitude to mean the number of digits in the number.  32767 is the largest integer than can fit into a signed 16 bit field.  If you move 32767 into a bit field with less than 15 bits, the number won't be 32767 any longer.  That's called narrowing.  If you move 32767 into a bit field with more than 15 bits (or 16 bits, signed), the value of 32767 will be retained.  That's called widening.

An order of magnitude is the addition or subtraction of a digit from the number.  For example, using base 10 integers, 32767 is an order of magnitude higher than 3276.  3276 is an order of magnitude higher than 327.

Comment: This appears to contradict the way "magnitude" is used quote in the question.  By the mathematical definition, a widening conversion from float to long could change the magnitude, because digits after the decimal point may be lost on conversion.

Comment: Unfortunately the magnitude they talk about in the JLS doesn't exactly fit this definition. It's close but not quite it.

Comment: @Julian Actually I got it the other way around: long->float is a widening conversion that can lose precision.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here's another attempt at a formal definition.

If `f(x)` is a widening conversion then for every `x <= y`, `f(x) <= f(y)`. In other words, widening conversions preserve a partial ordering of the values.

That's what not losing information about the overall magnitude might mean.

Loss of precision in this framework means that for some `x < y`, `f(x) = f(y)`.

---

The only problem with this definition is the `(float)Double.MAX_VALUE` overflow resulting `Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY`, which technically fulfils the criteria above but shouldn't really count as not losing information about the overall magnitude.

Comment: Should that last bit be `f(x) < f(y)`, rather than `f(x) = f(y)`?

Comment: @Julian No, because loss of precision means that some nearby values will be converted to the same value.